# Why does a module compile by itself but fail when used from elsewhere?

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have a Perl module that appears to compile fine by itself, but is causing other programs to fail compilation when it is included:

```
me@host:~/code $ perl -c -Imodules modules/Rebat/Store.pm
modules/Rebat/Store.pm syntax OK
me@host:~/code $ perl -c -Imodules bin/rebat-report-status
Attempt to reload Rebat/Store.pm aborted
Compilation failed in require at bin/rebat-report-status line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at bin/rebat-report-status line 4.
```

The first few lines of `rebat-report-status` are

```
...
3 use Rebat;
4 use Rebat::Store;
5 use strict;
...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Edit** (for posterity): Another reason for this to occur, and perhaps the most common reason, is that there is a circular dependency among the modules you are using.

---

Look in `Rebat/Store.pm` for clues. Your log says attempt to *reload* was aborted. Maybe `Rebat` already imports `Rebat::Store`, and `Rebat::Store` has some package-scope check against being loaded twice.

This code demonstrates the kind of situation I mean:

```
# m1.pl:
use M1;
use M1::M2;
M1::M2::x();

# M1.pm 
package M1;
use M1::M2;
1;

# M1/M2.pm
package M1::M2;
our $imported = 0;
sub import {
    die "Attempt to reload M1::M2 aborted.\n" if $imported++;
}
sub x { print "42\n" }
1;
```

---

```
$ perl m1.pl
Attempt to reload M1::M2 aborted.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at m1.pl line 3.
```

The code will compile (and print 42) if you just remove the `use M1::M2` line in `m1.pl`. In your case, you might not need to explicitly `use Rebat::Store` in your program.

Comment: The problem was, in fact, due to a newly introduced circular dependency between Rebat.pm and Rebat/Store.pm

Answer (score 5):

[perldoc perldiag](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html):

```
 Attempt to reload %s aborted.
           (F) You tried to load a file with "use" or "require" that failed to
           compile once already.  Perl will not try to compile this file again
           unless you delete its entry from %INC.  See "require" in perlfunc
           and "%INC" in perlvar.
```